# List down all details of students with their latest score card

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where unit test results are entered along with the student details. I want all the details of every student, but with the latest entry in the unit test column.

For example, if I tried to search sem4 data, where I entered a student record three times, as he gave three re-tests. I want the details of every student along with his latest test result.

```
SELECT * FROM table where sem= 4 GROUP BY student_name ORDER BY last-date DESC;
```

By this, my data is sorted with student name but not by the latest entry of the test result. It is one factor to filter.

Can someone provide me an SQL query for such a scenario?

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you show us your queries and the table?

Comment: Show sample input/output data for reference to your query.

Comment: would you please upload the table's attributes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got to use `group by student_id with having clause` as you want to have latest record per each student_id like

```
 select student_id, name, sem,last_date 
  as 
 last_updated from 
  table  group by student_id, name,sem having last_date=max(last_date)
```

Comment: No, You are replacing each student last exam date by your maximum date. that is not the case.

Comment: was a typo check now max(date) should be in having